# aptitude state is corrupt - how do I fix it?

Tags: aptitude

It appears that the `aptitude` state is corrupt - note that `apt-get` and the other `dpkg` tools still work fine. Is there some way to reset the state of aptitude?

Signs of corruption:

- `aptitude search` shows packages as 'p' (purged/never installed) when they are installed.
- If I try and `aptitude safe-upgrade` it tells me I need to uninstall half my system! But `apt-get upgrade` and the GUI update manager continue to work fine.

I find `aptitude search` very handy because of the package state information, so I would like to get that back again.

Note I am using 11.10, though I originally installed 9.10 and have upgraded through each release (and generally upgraded when the next release was in beta).

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation aptitude stores its own state (separate from the state of `apt-get` or `dpkg`) in `/var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates` and there may also be a configuration in `~/.aptitude/config`. Moving those files out of the way could help aptitude recover a sane state. As other tools are working, there's no harm in trying:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates /root/aptitude.pkgstates.backup
mv .aptitude .aptitude.backup
```

If aptitude starts working properly after those changes, you can remove the backups. If not, you can just put them back and try some other solution.